# How can I apply security patches to an offline freebsd machine?

Tags: freebsd

**Synopsis**:

We would like to use FreeBSD (version 11.0) on one of our products. Once the product leaves the company, it will be disconnected from the Internet for good. However, as part of our support policy, we are bound to provide regular patches including security patches for the OS and the installed software to the customers.

**Question**:

Is there a way to apply security patches to FreeBSD in an offline machine?

**What I have done so far**

After googling for days, below is the summary of what people suggest to do:

1. On an online machine exactly similar to the real machine a.k.a the offline machine, fetch the security patches:

> freebsd-update fetch

2. Transfer the contents of the /var/db/freebsd-update directory from the online machine to the offline machine.
3. Apply the patches on the offline machine:

> freebsd-update install

Provided the OS on the two machines are identical, this is expected to work. But my attempts so far have all been in vain. An error is displayed each time asking me to do the fetching step first by running:

> freebsd-update fetch

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.